# Is there a method to get recursion level of lock c#

Tags: c#, recursion, locking

I use a lock to block other threads in a section of my code. But I want to detect if the current thread re-enters this section to generate an exception if I have a recursion case. I do not want the thread to self deadlock if it is recursive. I want stop the program with a debug error message.

```
lock (x)
{
    if (getlLockLevel(x) > 1)   // Do not work, is the method I want to know
    {
        throw new Exception("ERROR : Current thread is recursive");
    }

    // My code...

}
```

Comment: You are locking `x`, so you will never enter inside the `lock { }` while the object is locked by another Thread. Also, why would it be "recursive" just because it calls a function twice? What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Ah, you meant that the locks is reentrant, not recursive. I still do not know what you want to achieve

Comment: Yes, I want to detect when the current thread re-enters this block of code to avoid this. My code has some recursive branches of the kind: methodA call Method B which call Method C which call Method A. But in this particular code block, recursion should not be allowed. I want to detect it to correct my code in this case.

Comment: Check `Monitor.IsEntered(x)` prior to issuing the lock?

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. It works very well. How can I accept your answer officially since it is in a comment to my question?

Comment: Maybe `ReaderWriterLockSlim` can help and `LockRecursionPolicy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Alex K.'s suggestion to modify my code as follows:

```
if (Monitor.IsEntered(x)   // That's what I want to check
{
    throw new Exception("ERROR : Current thread is reentrant");
}

lock (x)
{
    // My code...

}
```

I can now detect if the thread is re-entrant in a lock() section and treat it as needed.

Thanks Alex.